# User Input Date Range (mm/dd/yyyy)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in SQL and am trying to make a WHERE statement that allows the user to enter 2 dates, and all the data in between (and including) those dates are populated.

My code is currently 
`WHERE table.date BETWEEN 'StartDate' AND 'EndDate';`
But when I try to execute the query, I get an error that says "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." I also tried to take away the '' and I get another error that says "Invalid column name"

How can I fix this so that I can allow the user to enter a date (mm/dd/yyyy)?

Customer | Price | date | Items |

**EDIT**

Here's my actual code:

`SELECT [Customer],[Price],[Date],[Items]
FROM table
WHERE table.date BETWEEN ‘StartDate’ AND ‘EndDate’;`

Comment: Remove the single quotes around `StartDate` and `EndDate`.

Comment: I said above that I have tried that and it just tells me "Invalid column name"

Comment: the error suggests you are using sql-server. use the appropriate tags.

Comment: @nola94 can you show your table structure in your post? :)

Comment: Also as a note, for column names it's best to wrap them in backticks to avoid faulty execution (e.g. if a coulmn name was describe for some reason)

Comment: I tried to add a table, but I don't really know how @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs. Those are the titles of the columns if that helps

Comment: Single quotes quote '`string constants`'. Double quotes quote `"CaseSensitiveColumnNames"` with ANSI quotes enabled; MySQL also uses \`backticks\`  to quote such column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using Mysql you can cast the startdate and enddate which is string to date

```
between str_to_date(Startdate,'%m/%d/%Y') and str_to_date(EndDate,'%m/%d/%Y')
```

For Sql server

```
between convert(date, Startdate) and convert(date, Enddate)
```

For Example how you need to run all the script i added the screenshot. Assume startdate is @str1 and Enddate is @str2

```
Declare @Str1 Varchar(100)='12/14/2015'
Declare @Str2 Varchar(100)='12/14/2017'

select * from #temp where CONVERT(date,dat) between convert(date,@str1)
and CONVERT(date,@str2)
```

Screenshot for output:-

[image]

Comment: I get an error that reads " 'str_to_date' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: Which DBMS your using ? Mysql or SQL Server?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: @RohitPadma It gives me the same error that the column name is Invalid for StartDate and EndDate

Comment: @nola94 Can you post the exact script ?  if those are local variables you need to append @ as prefix to startdate/enddate

Comment: @RohitPadma I added the code to the bottom of the question

Comment: how are you getting startdate and enddate ? are they declared ?

Comment: Please do *not* post images of code.  Paste the code into your answer and format it.

Comment: Down vote for that ? gone crazy ? i just wanted the person to know about '@  '  I did add code check the answer  and still he was not able to get so i added a screenshot highlighting the required part. what wrong with that ? @Siyual

Comment: @RohitPadma Yes, I will absolutely downvote for that.  If you're posting code, post it as text, not a picture.  No one can copy/paste from a picture.  And in certain circumstances, some people can't even view the images.  So yes, I will downvote you for that.

Comment: @Siyual  FYI Check the question and answer - the code part i did keep it as code in the answer and read the comments. you will get to the reason why i did it. Still it doesn't make sense cannot help.

Comment: @ModusTollens Screenshot is just to highlight the @  or to show how to execute the whole query along with the variables . I did keep the code separately. Yeah i understand people use screen readers.

Comment: @RohitPadma https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3393505 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @Siyual Dude you just going by rules . Read the comments and you will understand why i did that. Don't you see the code in the answer. Anyways thanks for pointing out to the URLs. Have a great day.

Comment: @ModusTollens Thanks that for!  Down vote is just :(

Comment: @RohitPadma You're right, I am just going by the rules.  We have these rules for a reason - no need to get bent out of shape because I'm enforcing them.  No problem - you too!

Comment: @ModusTollens I just don't want  to argue on this more. I got your point. but I am telling i got a valid reason to do it.  There no code in the screenshot which will help. its same as in the description. You guys are seniors. Fine whatever ...Have a great day!

Comment: @RohitPadma Thank you. You actually earned my respect now! Thumbs up!

Comment: I could change but i just want to you guys to understand the situation for doing that. Code is no different from screenshots .  I recently started using stackoverflow though i joined a year ago may be i will learn with time. Anyways Thanks @ModusTollens

Comment: @RohitPadma You're welcome! I deleted my comments here because the issue is resolved.

Comment: I kinda need that picture...@RohitPadma

Comment: @Siyual  So  the person need the screenshot now :(

Comment: @nola94  What seriously after seeing  all the  conversation? you down voted for that ? :(

Comment: @RohitPadma I'm just kidding haha

Comment: @nola94  :) I have to learn all the guidelines of StackOverFlow